# Trunking between Juniper Ex3300 with Cisco Router

Tags: vlan, juniper

Hy Experts,

Please tell how to create trunking with Juniper and Cisco.

Cisco 2950 > Juniper EX3300 > Cisco 2621
I create VLAN 100,VLAN 200, VLAN 300

I have create trunk on juniper switch with :
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members

root@switch# set interfaces ge-0/0/23 unit 0 family ethernet-switching port-mode trunk

Now I want to telnet Juniper Switch from PC, but I don't know how to give IP address to Juniper switch and how to assign IP to vlan on Juniper switch.

Answer (score 0):

1, make sure to use 802.1Q trunk protocol on Cisco devices
2, match native VLAN settings on both ends
3, allow all used VLANs on the trunk, on both ends

For specific commands, please refer to the configuration guides from Cisco's and Juniper's websites